# Composer updates .htaccess file when updating

Tags: 8, composer

I am using composer with Drupal lightning. If I update Drupal via composer, it updates the .htaccess file.

Is there any way to prevent the .htaccess file from being overwritten?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 "extra": {
   "drupal-scaffold": { 
       "source": "http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/plain/{path}?h={version}", 
       "excludes": [ ".htaccess", "robots.txt" ]
       }
}
```

Put this above code in your composer.json file.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: This is correct, but see Arakwar's answer below. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/281526/48114

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer is correct and this prevent the .htacces file from being overwritten, most updates done to that files are linked to security issues. You should patch the file instead, as described in this answer : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/271147/25673

Here's a copy of the answer by Stef Van Looveren

> In the `scripts` section of your composer.json file, use the following:
>
> ```
> "post-drupal-scaffold-cmd": [
>   "patch -p0 < patches/htaccess.patch"
> ]
> ```
>
> (this requires "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold" in your `require` section)

Comment: This still won't work for certain elements of your .htaccess file because it pretty aggressively overwrites things such as BasePath which I need to be non-standard for a purpose I am using it for.

Comment: @Patrick if you are talking about the RewriteBase, which is part of the htaccess file, you just need to put your change in the patch file. This is exactly how you implement changes in the htaccess file while letting the base file from being updated when needed. This is how we implement more than a hundred of new lines and changes on our own htaccess file.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. I will try that soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way to append your changes at end of `.htaccess` file once its been updated by scaffold.

`htaccess-custom-changes.txt` contains your custom changes require to add.

```
"drupal-scaffold": {
  "file-mapping": {
    "[web-root]/.htaccess": {
      "append": "patches/htaccess-custom-changes.txt"
     }
}
```