# How to patch your htaccess file correctly in composer.json

Tags: 8, composer

After running `composer update` my Drupal installation gets updated, but it also changes the content of the .htaccess file each time.

How can I correctly patch it?

Comment: question was asked and answered by the same person at the same timestamp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `scripts` section of your composer.json file, use the following:

```
"post-drupal-scaffold-cmd": [
  "patch -p0 < patches/htaccess.patch"
]
```

(this requires "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold" in your `require` section)

Comment: Using `drupal-composer/drupal-project` I simply added one function to its [`ScriptHandler.php`](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/8.x/scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php) that always symlinks me my own `.htaccess` from the composer root dir as `post-install-cmd` and `post-update-cmd` into the web root dir.

Comment: @leymannx The problem with replacing it completely is that you won't get any changes that are done in core, the patch will keep them unless they conflict

Comment: And core .htacess changes are often (not always of course) security related, so it’s important to merge rather than overwrite changes

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I have successfully done it. This is for Drupal 8.9, but it should work for [a typical composer setup](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies).

Make sure you have [patching enabled and ready to go](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches), and know how to make a patch for drupal.

### Short version:

Patch the **core/assets/scaffold/files/htaccess** file and scope the patch as **'drupal/core'**.

### Long Version:

There are probably variations in method, but this is the gist of it:

1. Within the [web-root] folder create a temporary repo (if there is not already one there); e.g. `cd html && git init`
2. Add the core file to the repo;
   e.g. `git add core/assets/scaffold/files/htaccess`
3. Make your changes to `core/assets/scaffold/files/htaccess` and save it
4. Save the patch; e.g. `git diff core/assets/scaffold/files/htaccess > ../patches/htaccess.patch`
5. If you are not still using your repo, delete it; e.g. `rm -Rf [web-root]/.git`
6. Move back to your composer directory
7. Add the patch to the composer file "patches" section

```
"patches": {
  "drupal/core": {
      "Description of patch": "patches/htaccess.patch"
  }
}
```

8. Run `composer install`

That should patch the core "htaccess" file, and then the normal scaffolding flow will copy that file over to your [web-root]/.htaccess file.
Output should look similar to:

```
Gathering patches for root package.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
Gathering patches for root package.
Gathering patches for dependencies. This might take a minute.
  - Installing drupal/core (8.9.13): Loading from cache
  - Applying patches for drupal/core
    patches/htaccess.patch (Description of patch)
...
Scaffolding files for drupal/core:
 - Copy [web-root]/.htaccess from assets/scaffold/files/htaccess
```

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation. On my website I use a different htaccess on the local environment than on my remote environment. Therefore I added the htaccess to my gitignore file. I need this patch to only work on my remote server. Is there a way to do this?