# How do I avoid overwriting the .htaccess file when I use the Compose command?

Tags: installation, composer, 9, .htaccess

On my new Drupal 9 website, I customized the `.htaccess` file and the `robots.txt` file

I don't want its files to be overwritten when updating with Composer.

I added the lines below in my composer.json file but the `.htassess` file is overwritten every time. What's wrong with my code ? Thank you

```
"extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "./"
        },
        "file-mapping": {
            "[web-root]/.htaccess": false,
            "[web-root]/robots.txt": false
        }
    },
...
```

Comment: You may want to create a patch for your changes to the htaccess and robots.txt files and use composer to apply the patch rather than choosing to not update them. See [How to patch your htaccess file correctly in composer.json](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271146/how-to-patch-your-htaccess-file-correctly-in-composer-json)

Comment: Same Issue. In my case: I have added few redirections on .htaccess in Drupal. when i run the composer install/update, the .htaccess is resets in Drupal 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `.htaccess` and `robots.txt` are a part of Drupal core, they are called "Scaffold Files". When you do `composer update` it will download the repository version of these files.

You have to re-add your custom changes every time you do `composer update`.
Fortunately there is an [automated way to do this](https://github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold#altering-scaffold-files):

Option 1. Append your changes:

```
  "name": "my/project",
  ...
  "extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
      "file-mapping": {
        "[web-root]/robots.txt": {
          "append": "assets/my-robots-additions.txt",
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Option 2. Create patches:

```
  "name": "my/project",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "post-drupal-scaffold-cmd": [
      "cd docroot && patch -p1 <../patches/htaccess-ssl.patch"
    ]
  }
```

Option 3. Exclude (not recommended):

The official example:

```
  "name": "my/project",
  ...
  "extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
      "file-mapping": {
        "[web-root]/robots.txt": false
      }
    }
  }
```

The code, that you provided looks correct.

Make sure that you are using the https://github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold package and not the outdated https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold.

But this approach is not recommended, because you might miss important core changes/security fixes.

More details on [Altering Scaffold Files](https://github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold#altering-scaffold-files).