# Cannot enable file-mapping option in a composer.json to prevent custom edits to be overridden in .htaccess

Tags: composer

I have a "drupal/legacy-project" Drupal 9 project (it was packed inside bought custom drupal theme and later updated to latest drupal 9 version) and I need some custom edits in my root .htaccess file.
When I run "composer update" all my custom edits in .htacess are gone and my site is immediately broken. Composer output:

```
Scaffolding files for drupal/core:
- Copy [web-root]/.htaccess from assets/scaffold/files/htaccess
```

I want my root .htaccess updated with a core updates since there might be some security updates in the future. But also I want to keep my custom lines in the .htaccess.
So I tried to implement file-mapping option in my composer.json:

```
"file-mapping": {
  "[web-root]/.htaccess": {
    "prepend": "assets/my_htaccess_additions.txt"
  }
}
```

But instead of prepending my custom lines from assets/my_htaccess_additions.txt file to root .htaccess I got no scaffolding at all and this text in my composer output:

```
Scaffolding files for drupal/core:
Skip [web-root]/.htaccess: overridden in drupal/legacy-project
```

Why is that and why composer mentions two projects (drupal/core and drupal/legacy-project) instead of one?
Also I need to mention that this file-mapping setup works perfectly in my dev environment, but not in my prod environment

Thanks.

My system: ubuntu 18.04, php7.4, apache2.
My composer.json contents:

```
{
"name": "drupal/legacy-project",
"description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with composer following drupal/drupal layout",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
"support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.9",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.1",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^5.2",
    "drupal/block_visibility_groups": "^1.4",
    "drupal/color_field": "^2.5",
    "drupal/colorbox": "^1.10",
    "drupal/commerce": "^2.30",
    "drupal/commerce_currency_resolver": "^1.60",
    "drupal/commerce_shipping": "^2.4",
    "drupal/commerce_stock": "^1.0",
    "drupal/contact_block": "^1.6",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.4",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.4",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.4",
    "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^9.4",
    "drupal/ctools": "^4.0",
    "drupal/entity_reference_facet_link": "^2.0",
    "drupal/facets": "^2.0",
    "drupal/facets_pretty_paths": "^1.2",
    "drupal/field_timer": "^1.2",
    "drupal/flag": "^4.0@beta",
    "drupal/fontawesome": "^2.23",
    "drupal/image_delta_formatter": "^1.1",
    "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/lang_dropdown": "^2.0",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.10",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.7",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.24",
    "drupal/simplenews": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/token": "^1.10",
    "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.4",
    "drupal/votingapi": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/votingapi_widgets": "^1.0@alpha"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/installers": true,
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
        "drupal/core-project-message": true,
        "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": true,
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "./"
        },

    "file-mapping": {
    "[web-root]/.htaccess": {
      "prepend": "assets/my_htaccess_additions.txt"
    }
  }

    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "profiles/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-profile"
        ],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
        "include-keys": [
            "homepage",
            "support"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/legacy-project template!               </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "",
            "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
            "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
            "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
            "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
            "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
            "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
            "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
            "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You win an unofficial community award for posting composer.json! Almost every question about Composer omits it. Take a bow. And IMO patching .htaccess is superior. I think the reason you see drupal/legacy-project in output is because that is the name value for your project, and you can configure that value any way you wish.

Comment: @cilefen haha, thanks, will learn patching, looks like I cannot fix that file-mapping feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to patch your htaccess file correctly in composer.json](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271146/how-to-patch-your-htaccess-file-correctly-in-composer-json)

Comment: Yes, this is also documented in the [README](https://github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold/blob/9.5.x/README.md?plain=1#L133). Also, it looks like your project structure is a little unorthodox. It looks like you're not putting your web root in a subdirectory - normally the structure would have your composer.json at project root, alongside things like config and vendor, and then core, modules, themes, etc inside `project_root/web`.

Comment: @cilefen, to be precise it does not answer original question (about file-mapping), but looks like it can solve the issue another way, thank you.

Comment: @sonfd, it's called drupal/legacy-project, as said in the post, this is the one of possible drupal composer project templates.

Comment: This has appeared as a bug report, so we should close the question now https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3309090.